# adding jar file dependencies

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-tool-suite

I have a Maven project that I've taken over and imported to Spring Tool Suite.

I added the Java facet so I could use "Open Declaration" and "References" to find out info about various classes used in the code.

The problem is, now I've got all kinds of errors because jar files (managed in the pom files) aren't on the Java build path.  I've got them all in my .m2 directory but really don't want to add them by hand (there are about 100 or more buried in a deep directory structure)

Do I have any options to detect automatically or something that will prevent me from adding them 1 by 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select your project in STS (Sprint Tool Suite)/ Eclipse
    -> (Right-Click)
        -> Maven
            -> Update Project (shortcut Alt+F5)
                -> (Check all, except 'Offline' option) and press Ok
```

It will rebuild your project and hope solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help.  I still have errors related to classes that do not exist.  When I hover over them sometimes I am prompted to add a jar from my .m2 repository OR manually configure the build path.

Comment: Can you please share your pom.xml and exact error message you are getting ?